# How to replace last line in Windows batch code?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a text-based game, and when the user enters something, I want the computer's character to have some kind of thinking animation.

I've come up with this: [.  ] [.. ] [...]

Only problem is, I want it all to be on one line, so it's like an actual animation. I've successfully recreated this *without* removed the text already echo'd, but it requires that you cls, then send all that was on the screen before, **three** times. Obviously this takes too much space and is pretty inefficient.

I found a code that changes the last like without clearing all that was before it,

```
@echo off
echo This won't disappear!
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~f0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
for /L %%n in (5 -1 1) do (
  <nul set /P "=This window will close in %%n seconds!CR!"
  ping -n 2 localhost > nul
)
```

It counts down without erasing the echo before, but I do not understand how to adapt it to add periods to my string... Does anyone know a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Back when computers were really slow, you could make a funny prompt by including Ctrl-H (backspace) in the prompt string.  That's the last time I looked at batch files in any detail.  Perhaps you can do something with that.

Comment: @Eric: yes, I used to work with such stuff back in DOS-Days. It doesn't work in `cmd` (no ANSI-Support any more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there with the code you found; you just need to use your own text instead of somebody else's.

```
for /L %%A in (1,1,3) do (
    set /p "=."<nul 
    ping -n 2 localhost >nul
)
```

If you want to put the periods inside of brackets, you can use this:

```
for /f %%A in ('"prompt $H &echo on &for %%B in (1) do rem"') do set BS=%%A

set /p "=[   ]"<nul
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
set /p "=%BS%%BS%%BS%%BS%.  ]"<nul
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
set /p "=%BS%%BS%%BS%. ]"<nul
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
set /p "=%BS%%BS%.]"<nul
ping -n 2 localhost >nul
```

Comment: Will this include brackets and repeat until there are 3 periods though?

Comment: Oh, you didn't explicitly mention the brackets, so I thought you were just using them to separate the periods...